# Cout is an object of ostream_withassign class

Tags: c++, io

[image]Till now i believe that cout is an object of ostream class . But today i read in a book that cout is an object of osream_withassign class. 
Where is this class located.

I am new to concept of Input/Output in C++ .So please if anyone can explain me the hierachy of classes in iostream library?
I googled but din't find any exact answer.

EDIT: i am attaching an image i found later on in the same book .

Answer (score 4):

The standard seems to require `std::cout` to have the type
`std::ostream`.  Historically, in classical (pre-standard)
iostream, it had to be `ostream` *or* a type derived from
`ostream`.  (It was unspecified which, so the implementation
didn't have to document it.)  I suspect that this is an
accidental over-specification in the standard, but that's the
way it stands.

There has never been a "standard" class `ostream_withassign`
that you could count on.  In classical iostreams, before the
standard, at least one implementation did have such a class,
which it used for `cout` (no `std::` back then), in order to
manage initialization, although I'm not sure of the details.  As
far as I know, even then, this was an implementation detail, and
not specified, even by the implementation.  It wasn't
widespread; none of the implementations I used back then had it,
and it doesn't exist in any implementation I'm aware of today.

So the book is extremely dated.  And if the book claims to be
about C++, it is wrong, even back then.  And if it claims to be
about a specific implementation of C++, it depends: if it is
describing internal details, it is correct, but if it claims to
be describing the interface, it is wrong.

Comment: Please have a look at the image which i have uploaded. 
(The book is C++ specific)

Comment: @gandhi_rahul That _might_ be the way some specific implementation implemented iostream 15 years ago.  It's not relevant today, and even then, it was very implementation specific.

Comment: Ok. That means the implementation pattern has changed . Right!?

Comment: @gandhi_rahul It means that each implementation does what it thinks best.  And that the strategy described above isn't legal in modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

About actual hierarchy you can read standard of the C++ language, or look [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream)

`std::cout` is an object of type `std::ostream`, which is typedef on `std::basic_ostream<char>`.